# Why wasn't Gates McFadden removed from the opening credits of season 2 of TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This is not a question about why Gates McFadden left TNG; that's been discussed elsewhere.  My question is, why didn't they remove her name from the opening credits?  Did they not have the budget to make new credits?  Was her dismissal sudden enough that they didn't have time to edit the credits?

EDIT: I remembered McFadden being credited on the season 2 episodes when I watched them in syndication more than 20 years ago.  However, it appears that either my memory was faulty or that there were changes made between versions, as online videos don't seem to have her credit.  So, perhaps my question makes a false assumption.  It would be interesting to see if anyone who has some of the earlier versions (such as on VHS) could confirm or deny her credit.

Comment: Probably contractual...these things usually are.

Comment: IIRC she only left temporarily due to mat leave. As @Paulie_D mentioned, there was probably contractual stuff involved as well. Denise Crosby's name remained on the credits for the season when she left the show as well.

Comment: @Vanguard3000 No the reason she left was somewhat...erm..darker (allegedly), It's out there on the interweb if you really want to know. It's covered on SF&F too.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22969/why-was-crusher-replaced-with-pulaski-who-was-replaced-by-crusher?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Oh snap! Thanks for the clarification, @Paulie_D.

Comment: @Paulie_D:  That may be, but it's a strange contract if it's still in force after she left.  I would like to see confirmation if it's the case.  Unless there was a new deal more like "we recognize our part in your leaving (hostile work environment or worse) so we're willing to continue to pay you X and leave your name on the credits..."   Something like that would at least make some sense.

Comment: This is quite interesting. In some markets they removed her name. In others they didn't. I initially thought it would have been a contractual thing but I'm starting to think that it was down to advert timing

Comment: I just checked several episodes of Season 2 on Netflix (Canada) and her name isn't in the credits. It skips from Michael Dorn directly to Marina Sirtis.

Comment: @ThePopMachine The closest thing I can think of is the flap over Claudia Christian's credits in *Babylon 5*. She was in the 4th but not 5th season; when the series finale was moved from S4 to S5 (long story) they couldn't have her *or her credit* in the replacement S4 episode - because she was contracted based on *number of episodes* rather than by season. So there can be odd riders, but that was a case of episodes already filmed, not future episodes.